# How to fetch AWS CodeDeploy logs and show them in a BitBucket pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-code-deploy, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to fetch CodeDeploy logs from my Amazon EC2 instance when a script fails during deployment and then show the logs in BitBucket pipelines.

How can I do that?
Is there any API available for fetching the logs from CodeDeploy?

Comment: Sometimes I am surprised by AWS. They leave such minor but important stuff and look the other way like that meme face. codedeploy should provide API to read the logs directly, not through cloudwatch or s3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about BitBucket, but natively on AWS, you can push the logs from CodeDeploy agent to CloudWatch Logs using the CloudWatch Logs agent [1]. Once in CloudWatch Logs, you will create a Metric Filter to Alarm when some specific text appears in the log entries [2].

CodeDeploy agent log file locations are:

```
LINUX 
*** /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/deployment-group-ID/deployment-ID/logs/scripts.log
*** /var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log
*** /tmp/codedeploy-agent.update.log
WINDOWS 
*** C:\ProgramData\Amazon\CodeDeploy\log\codedeploy-agent-log.txt
*** C:\ProgramData\Amazon\CodeDeploy\deployment-group-ID\deployment-ID\logs\scripts.log
*** C:\ProgramData\Amazon\CodeDeployUpdater\log\codedeploy-agent.updater.log
```

References:

[1] Quick Start: Enable Your Amazon EC2 Instances Running Windows Server 2016 to Send Logs to CloudWatch Logs Using the CloudWatch Logs Agent  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartWindows2016.html

[2] https://theithollow.com/2017/12/11/use-amazon-cloudwatch-logs-metric-filters-send-alerts/

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not aware of any API to get this done, I have a simple workaround which does the job - this involves uploading the default code deployment log file to S3 and reading from there.

1. On the EC2 instance the default log file for AWS Code Deploy is stored here: /var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log
2. Install aws-cli on the EC2 instance.[1]
3. Write a simple shell script which uploads the log file to S3 bucket. For convenience sake, you may use the same S3 bucket which is being used to upload code from bitbucket to EC2 instance. However make sure that the EC2 instance has enough privileges to upload a file to the S3 bucket. [2]

   `#!/bin/bash`

   `aws s3 cp /var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log s3://S3_BUCKET_NAME/codedeploy-agent.log`
4. Let's say that the script created in the above step is saved here: /opt/upload-log-file.sh. Make sure that the script has read privileges for code deploy to be able to upload it to S3. This can be ensured by running the command:

   `chmod +r /opt/upload-log-file.sh`
5. The appspec.yml defines all the steps for the deployment. In the script of the last defined step (usually the 'ValidateService' step) add the following line to execute the upload-log-file.sh script:

   `/opt/upload-log-file.sh`
6. In the bitbucket-pipelines.yml file, add the following steps to read the contents of the uploaded log file. Note that the variables used here should be declared in the bitbucket user-defined variables. [3]

   `apt-get update`

   `apt-get install -y awscli`

   `export aws_access_key_id=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID; export aws_secret_access_key=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY; aws s3 cp s3://$S3_BUCKET_NAME/codedeploy-agent.log .`

   `tail -100 codedeploy-agent.log`

The next time bitbucket pipelines are run, you will be able to see the last 100 lines of the log file in the pipeline steps.

---

References:

[1] Installing AWS CLI - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-install.html

[2] Accessing AWS S3 from EC2 - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-access-s3-bucket/

[3] Bitbucket Variables and Secrets - https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/